# Export output of an array for population of agent in Anylogic

Tags: arrays, export, anylogic, agent

I'm new with Anylogic and I would like to export one string array in excell file after running the model for each population of agent. I don't know it's possible or not. Any suggestions?
This array is different for each population. for example:
1: Croparray=[Alfa, Walnut, Pome, Wheat, Potato]
2: Croparray=[Potato, Walnut, Wheat, Alfa, Pome]
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the example model and the help file for more information on writing to Excel

https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/excel-file.html

You will need to

- link an Excel file
- set a cell value
- write the excel file

The code to write to an excel Cell is

```
excelFile.setCellValue( cellStringValue, cellName );
```